# SPSS: Want to copy same datediff function across many different date variables and generate multiple result variables

Tags: spss

I am very new to SPSS and statistical programs in general. I've searched for the answer to this question but can't seem to find a straightforward answer.

I have one date variable (dateA) that I want to compare to multiple other date variables (date1, date2, date3...date1000+) with the datediff function, and create a separate datediff result variable for each computation.

I have tried doing this through the "compute variable" process on SPSS but it only allows me to choose a pair of dates at a time (i.e. adding the "TO" function for date1 TO dateX doesn't work). I would rather create an automated process to do this function for all of these other date variables automatically, and create datediff results for each (datediff1, datediff2, datediff3...).

e.g. dateA - date1 = datediff1; dateA - date2 = datediff2; dateA - date3 = datediff3...and so on (without having to compute each manually which would take forever).

The end goal is to find out how many of these many datediff results are <= 2 weeks.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use this to create some sample data:

```
DATA LIST FREE /dateA date1 date2 date3 (4ADATE10).
BEGIN DATA
1/1/2017 1/2/2017  1/7/2017   1/12/2017
1/2/2017 1/16/2017  1/10/2017  1/14/2017
1/3/2017 1/29/2017  2/1/2017  2/7/2017
END DATA.
```

Now to create a new set of variables containing the difference between the dates you can use `do repeat` to loop through the dates and compare them:

```
do repeat DtList=date1 to date3/Diff=Diff1 to Diff3.
    compute Diff=datediff(DtList, dateA, "weeks").
end repeat.

* now you can count the number of dates that have a two weeks difference or more.
COUNT Weeks2p=Diff1 Diff2 Diff3 (2 thru Hi).
```

But if all you need is to get the final count, you can do it without creating all the difference wariables, like this:

```
compute Weeks2p=0.
do repeat DtList=date1 to date3/Diff=Diff1 to Diff3.
    compute Weeks2p=Weeks2p + (datediff(DtList, dateA, "weeks") ge 2).
end repeat.
```

Comment: Hi eli-k, thanks so much for your response!

I've tried entering in your code, along with changing the variable names to reflect those in my actual data file, as such:

DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
do repeat DtList=addate_converted.1 to addate_converted.185/DeathAdmDateDiff=DeathAdmDateDiff.1 to DeathAdmDateDiff.185.
    compute DeathAdmDateDiff=datediff(DtList, deathdt_ddmmmyyyy, "weeks").
end repeat.

COUNT Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff=DeathAdmDateDiff.1 to DeathAdmDateDiff.185 (2 thru LO).
execute.

Comment: However, when I run the above expression the output simply says "execute" and nothing else happens. Am I missing something in the expression to implement it for each case in my dataset?

I want the output to be new variables Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff.1 to Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff.185 for each case, for each datediff of deathdt_ddmmmyyyy to addate_converted.1 through addate_converted.185

Comment: After the `do repeat` you'll see 185 new variables added to your dataset with the new names: DeathAdmDateDiff.1 to DeathAdmDateDiff.185 . After running the `count` you should see in your dataset the new variable Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff. All these are changes to the dataset, but nothing should apprear yet in the output because we didn't ask for any report or analysis yet. For that add, after the `count`, `frequencies Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff.`

Comment: Also, in `count`, you can't use `(2 thru LO)` - you can use `(## thru HI)` or `(LO thru ##)`. If you are trying to count the low numbers because you got negative differences, try reversing the order of the variables in your `DATEDIFF` command.

Comment: Ah thank you eli-k, that makes sense! I was able to run the program which created the new variables.

One specifier I forgot to include was the fact that each case may have multiple associated dates; e.g. case 1 may have several DeathAdmDateDiff variables that are <= 2 weeks. However, I only want to count the existence of at least one date difference of <=2 weeks for each case. Basically, I want to know how many cases had at least one date difference of <= 2 weeks. Is there an easy way to incorporate this into the existing code?

Comment: The eventual goal is to compare those cases that did have date differences less than 2 weeks to those who didn't.

Comment: `Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff` will contain the number of "datediffs" that are 2 weeks or less. now you can use `compute AtLeast1=(Weeks2pDeathAdmDateDiff>0). ` . variable AtLeast1 will be 0 if no diff was <=2 and 1 if at least one diff was <=2.